# Run specific job in Gitlab with QraphQL

Tags: graphql, gitlab-api

There is possible to replace two below REST API queries and replace them by one graphql query?

```
const response = await axiosInstance.get(`/projects/${cdProjectId}/jobs?scope=manual&per_page=100&order_by=id`, axiosConfig);

const data = response.data.map(({id, stage, name, pipeline, created_at}) => ({id, stage, name, pipeline: pipeline.id, created_at })).reverse();
const jobId = data[0].id;

await axiosInstance.post(`/projects/${cdProjectId}/jobs/${jobId}/play`, undefined, axiosConfig);
```

I would like to the play last manual job from specific project passed by `cdProjectId` variable. 
There is `Mutation.playJob` in [Gitlab Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/graphql/reference/#mutationjobplay) but it requires `id` as argument and I'm not sure there is some way to get this information in the same mutation